# Create single .mat file by using multiple wave signal

Tags: matlab

I want to prepare training and testing set for Automatic Speech Recognition by using a Matlab toolbox. I already have the sample set containing  several recorded audio (.wav). I am new to Matlab. In order to use the toolbox I need to create training ad testing set save in .mat file. The question is how to create single .mat file containing all the audio? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

To create disjoint training and testing set, the best method is to use `crossvalind` command. So it performs cross-validation of `k-fold` where `k` is the parameter given as input. If `k=5` then `1/5th` data is used for testing and `4/5th` data is used for training. The code is as follows:

```
 data=randi(20,[500 20]); %creating random data with 500 rows and 20 columns.
 indices=crossvalid('Kfold',size(data,1),5);
 test = (indices == 2); %you can put any number between 1 to 5
 train = ~test;
 trainData=data(train,:);
 testData=data(test,:); 
 savefile='dataFile.mat'
 save(savefile,'trainData','testData');
```

If you change the number 2 to other number, you will get train-test data with a same distribution and it will be random each time. You can also put it in a for loop but then for saving, you will need to use some tricks or do it manually by placing a breakpoint each point to avoid data getting overwritten. This a general technique to create train-test sets. I hope you will be able to apply this for your problem.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply.I tried to run the coding but I got this error:Undefined function 'crossvalid' for input arguments of type 'char'.
How can I solve this error? Thank you

Comment: Hi @Parag, I am sorry , I overlooked at the spelling of crossvalid supposed to be crossvalind in your comment. I run the codding and it gave me test and training set but with  the (100x20 for test data) and (400x20 for train data). How to change the coding so that i can input my wave signal into the .mat file? Let say I have 100 .wav signal for test and 100 for train data. (e.g: voice001.wav, voice002.wav , voice003.wav). Your help is really appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: so you will have `100x20` train data and same number of test data right? Then I have given the `save` command, doesn't that serve the purpose?

Comment: Hi Parag,Thanks a lot I combined the save command with a command I got somewhere in the internet:for k=1:3
htrain{k}=wavread(sprintf('%d.wav',k));
end
savefile='training_list.mat'
save(savefile,'htrain')
for k1=4:6
htrain1{k1}=wavread(sprintf('%d.wav',k1));
end
savefile1='testing_list.mat'; 
save(savefile,'htrain1')... it helps me. Thanks for the help its great!